# Retrieve --packageversion passed from TeamCity as a command line argument

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

When I create release from TeamCity, I specify `--packageversion %build.number%` as an additional command line argument. Is there a way to read that variable in Octopus Deploy?

Looking at documentation, I've found only one variable containing "packageversion": `Octopus.Action.Package.NuGetPackageVersion`and it doesn't seem like what I need as it is specific to a step and I want to get a global --packageversion (also known as defaultpackageversion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are driving the release from TC and you are passing in a package version (i.e. there is a nuget package), then this will become your release number.

Looking at the inbuilt system variables, you could use

**Octopus.Release.Number**

This will also be the number entered when doing a manual deployment.

[Octopus System Variables](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/System+variables)

Hope this helps